# How to use Sass to generate various theme sets with minor differences

Tags: css, sass

I have a solution which server various customers. Each customer has it's own theme, meaning a set of CSS files. There are a couple of elements, which are changing from customer to customer, so I'm using Sass to generate CSS files, using variables. Is there any solution to simplify below setup as it seems too complex,

```
├sass
│  ├CUSTOMER1
│  │  ├login.scss
│  │  ├style.scss
│  │  ├variable.scss
│  ├CUSTOMER2
│  │  ├login.scss
│  │  ├style.scss
│  │  ├variable.scss
│  ├login-base.scss
│  └style-base.scss
└compilerconfig.json
```

**login-base.scss** and **style-base.scss** contain the actual CSS, where variables are used.

Content of each **login.scss** (so the same file is present in each and every customer folder):

```
@import "variable";
@import "../login-base.scss";
```

Content of each **style.scss** (so the same file is present in each and every customer folder):

```
@import "variable";
@import "../style-base.scss";
```

**variable.css** varies across customers.

Content of **compilerconfig.json**:

```
[
  //CUSTOMER1
  {
    "outputFile": "(MyProjectPath)/themes/CUSTOMER1/login.css",
    "inputFile": "sass/CUSTOMER1/login.scss"
  },
  {
    "outputFile": "(MyProjectPath)/themes/CUSTOMER1/style.css",
    "inputFile": "sass/CUSTOMER1/style.scss"
  },
  //CUSTOMER2
  {
    "outputFile": "(MyProjectPath)/themes/CUSTOMER2/login.css",
    "inputFile": "sass/CUSTOMER2/login.scss"
  },
  {
    "outputFile": "(MyProjectPath)/themes/CUSTOMER2/style.css",
    "inputFile": "sass/CUSTOMER2/style.scss"
  }
]
```

Is there any way to simplify above setup? All my login.scss and style.scss files are exactly the same in all customer directories, which is redundant.
Whenever a new customer comes (and we are serving tens of customers, potentially hundreds), I need to create a new folder, place all the files in the folder, make changes to the compilerconfig.json and change set the variable.scss content according to customers needs. So I'm doing a lot of steps, creating a good amount of files, but only one file really changes: variable.scss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you could make a separate variables.scss file for all of the users, but every other scss files could be in the same directory like this.

```
├sass
|  |GLOBAL
|  |  |login.scss
|  |  |styles.scss
│  ├CUSTOMER1
│  │  ├variable.scss
│  ├CUSTOMER2
│  │  ├variable.scss
│  ├login-base.scss
│  └style-base.scss
└compilerconfig.json
```

in your `variables.scss` files you could write global vars as CSS variables like this:

```css
:root{
  --primary-color: blue;
  --secondary-color: red;
  --font-family: sans-serif
/* etc. */
}
```

and in your scss files, you could use these vars without duplicate anything like this:

```scss
.my-button{
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

or like this

```scss
$primary-color: var(--primary-color);
.my-button{
  background-color: $primary-color
}
```

after that you just have to generate each user `variables.css` files, but the page will use the same `styles.scss` and `login.scss` files like that:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="variables.css"> <!-- variables needs to be the first one -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

your config file should look like this:

```json
[
  //GLOBAL
  {
    "outputFile": "(MyProjectPath)/themes/GLOBAL/login.css",
    "inputFile": "sass/Global/login.scss"
  },
  {
    "outputFile": "(MyProjectPath)/themes/GLOBAL/styles.css",
    "inputFile": "sass/Global/styles.scss"
  },
  //CUSTOMER1
  {
    "outputFile": "(MyProjectPath)/themes/CUSTOMER1/variables.css",
    "inputFile": "sass/CUSTOMER1/variables.scss"
  },
  //CUSTOMER2
  {
    "outputFile": "(MyProjectPath)/themes/CUSTOMER2/variables.css",
    "inputFile": "sass/CUSTOMER2/variables.scss"
  },
]
```

hope it helps!